# Choosing between GeoTools and uDig?

Tags: google-maps, java, software-recommendations, geotools, udig

I am trying to develop a java application that displays : Google maps, Openstreetmap and Bing Map Data.

So which is the best SDK to use in this contet Geotools or uDig ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how advanced application you will be creating. I recommend downloading uDig, and starting the application. If it looks close to what you need, then go for uDig. If you want a more low-level API, then you should select GeoTools (which uDig is built on top of).